# DVD drive activates every time I save a text file, and at other inappropriate times

Tags: 22.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, dvd

I am writing a text file on my laptop.

However, every time I save the text file, the DVD drive activates.  The DVD drive also activates at other inappropriate times.

I could eject the DVD of course, but it's easier to keep the DVD in the drive for when I use the DVD later.  Nonetheless, saving a text file shouldn't affect the DVD drive in any way.

My system is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

How can I make the DVD drive only start up when it should start up?